# Azure Sql Sync Frequency(Continuous synchronization or interval less than 5 minutes)

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure SQL Data Sync, i'm seeing current smallest interval for sync is 5 minutes, can i get option to set this to between 1 and 4 minutes or a continuous synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

not..if you use azure portal to setup the sync, 5 minutes are the least interval time. however you may use Powershell scripts or Azure SQL RESTApi to trigger the sync manually from your application level.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that it is possible to do data sync below 5 minutes, [from the documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/).

You can read about your other options for [Data Replication and Synchronization here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589787.aspx).